# how to substring between to characters in javascript?

Tags: javascript

my js code is:

```
 var str = window.location.hash.substring(window.location.hash.indexOf("/MinPrice") + 1, window.location.hash.lastIndexOf("/"));
                            if (str != "") {
                                window.location.hash = window.location.hash.replace(str, "MinPrice-" + start + "/" + "MaxPrice-" + end);

                            }
                            else {
                                window.location.hash = window.location.hash + "/MinPrice-" + start + "/" + "MaxPrice-" + end + "/";

                            }
```

my string is :==>
isAvailable/MinPrice-1501/MaxPrice-4000/type-Android/

or:==> /MinPrice-1501/MaxPrice-4000/isAvailable/type-Android/

or:==>/isAvailable/type-Android/MinPrice-1501/MaxPrice-4000

or  ....

i want to substring **MinPrice-1501/MaxPrice-4000/** from above string and replace by other string.

Comment: You should provide more detail on how you want to achieve it and show us what you have done to achieve your target. This is for people who need help in fixing their problems - not a "do my code" service

Comment: `'isAvailable/MinPrice-1501/MaxPrice-4000/type-Android/'.split('/').slice(1,-2).join('/')`

Answer (score 0):

Use `substring` with correct indexes:

```
"isAvailable/MinPrice-1501/MaxPrice-4000/type-Android/".substring(12,40)
```